# MySQL 5.0 slow for order by index

Tags: php, mysql, indexing

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM projects WHERE current = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,20
```

`id` is the primary key, and there is an index created for `current` and `status` field

```
CREATE INDEX currentstatus ON projects (current, status)
```

The table has 30,000+ rows, and this query runs in about 4.0s

I would like to use `force index for group by (id)` but MySQL 5.0 does not support it.

Explain shows the `currentstatus` is used for the query, but I would have liked to use `currentstatus` for the `WHERE` clause, and `PRIMARY` for the `ORDER BY` clause

We cannot upgrade the database as this is heavily used and we cannot have any downtime. I am wondering if there is a way to optimize this query in MySQL 5.0 so it will use the primary key index when sorting?

**EDIT:** The ideal query, as an example, in MySQL 5.1+ would be

```
SELECT * FROM projects FORCE INDEX FOR ORDER BY (PRIMARY) WHERE current = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,20;
```

Comment: You could add an index on `(current, id)` (one index for both columns) although I am not sure if that is optimized when you order `DESC` in mysql 5.0.

Comment: As far as I'm aware sorting in mysql is nearly always after selection.  Use Explain to see if it's using that index, I suspect not.

Comment: Using one index to select and another to sort does not work—no matter which MySQL version. Go for the `(current, id)` index as suggested by @jeroen.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson It is using the currentstatus index for sorting, which is why the query is running so slowly. If it was using the PRIMARY index this would be optimized, which is where the problem comes in. MySQL 5.0 you cannot specify which index to use on the ORDER BY clause. In MySQL 5.1+ you can specify this.

Comment: @MarkusWinand - using 2 separate indexes can be used for select / group by using force index. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html shows how to use this syntax. But this is not available before MySQL 5.1

Comment: @jeroen - I think this is a good suggestion (although seems silly to index the primary key again). When I can I will try this, but it takes about 30+ mins to setup an index on this table, so waiting for a good time.

Comment: @newms87 Yes, the syntax allows specifiying multiple hints for different scope, but it does not work they way you think. In the end, it just means use either this index for the WHERE or that index for the ORDER BY. Sort order is always lost upon index merge, hence you cannot use multiple indexes and still take benefit of the order of one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution that is more of a workaround for the issue. This will at least allow for much faster queries:

```
SELECT * FROM projects WHERE current = 1 AND id > ((SELECT MAX(id) FROM projects) - 1000) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20;
```

This will default to using the PRIMARY key `id` for the order by / where clauses and it is a small enough subset to scan through that this query runs in 0.00s vs 4.35s on my current data set. 1000 rows will guarantee at least 20 records with `current = 1` for this case anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 5.0 as you have mentioned it is not possible to force / use a specific index for only the ORDER BY clause.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index-hints.html

And MySQL 5.1+ does indeed allow this.

It is for this reason they probably added this feature in for MySQL 5.1

Comment: I think you are right. I will try to find another work aroudn